# wolkenkit without Docker

Tags: wolkenkit

Can I install wolkenkit without Docker?

I tried to do wolkenkit run but I faced a Docker problem, this is because I use VirtualBox and I am not planning to use Docker at all on my PC.

Can I run blank project without Docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can, try to install it with npm or yarn, like
`npm install wolkenkit`

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer is wrong (installing it via `npm` only installs the CLI, not wolkenkit itself).

Comment: But I can make use of its LIBs within the project without the need to run it from the CLI

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no

wolkenkit consists of two parts: The [wolkenkit CLI](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit) and a variety of Docker images. As the CLI was written in Node.js, you can install it without Docker (but this is only true for the CLI). To do so, you should install it using the `-g` flag of `npm`:

```
$ npm install -g wolkenkit
```

The Docker images, of course, rely on Docker. So basically, yes, you need to have a machine that runs Docker to run wolkenkit. Depending on your operating system, see the installation guides of wolkenkit:

- [macOS](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/3.0.0/getting-started/installing-wolkenkit/installing-on-macos/)
- [Windows](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/3.0.0/getting-started/installing-wolkenkit/installing-on-windows/)
- [Linux](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/3.0.0/getting-started/installing-wolkenkit/installing-on-linux/)

If you don't want to install Docker on your machine, you can still set it up on a remote machine, e.g. using [docker-machine](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/3.0.0/getting-started/installing-wolkenkit/installing-using-docker-machine/). Then you can control that remote machine using the locally installed wolkenkit CLI.

Another option is to use a ready-made virtual machine that already contains wolkenkit: These machines are available for VMware and VirtualBox, and can easily be set up using [Vagrant](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/3.0.0/getting-started/installing-wolkenkit/installing-using-vagrant/).

I hope this helps

*PS: Please note that I am one of the core developers of wolkenkit.*

Comment: Thank you very much, I will download the virtual box images if I found it a good fit, will try it and respond if I have more questions

Comment: Do you have any download links for these machines (Virtual Box)?

Comment: Alright, thanks, it is here
https://app.vagrantup.com/thenativeweb/boxes/wolkenkit/versions/3.0.0